# how to get back value select in react-select Async

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I create an async select with `react-select`.I can show value get from API. but when user select one of them, how to find which one is selected.
this is `loadOptions` method:

```
const loadOptions = (selectedOption, callback) => {
        let xml = `my xml data`;
        axios.post('test.com', xml, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8' } }).then(function (response) {
            //console.log(response)
            var options = {
                attributeNamePrefix: "@_",
                attrNodeName: "attr", //default is 'false'
                textNodeName: "#text",
                ignoreAttributes: true,
                ignoreNameSpace: false,
                allowBooleanAttributes: false,
                parseNodeValue: true,
                parseAttributeValue: false,
                trimValues: true,
                cdataTagName: "__cdata", //default is 'false'
                cdataPositionChar: "\\c",
                localeRange: "", //To support non english character in tag/attribute values.
                parseTrueNumberOnly: false,
                attrValueProcessor: a => he.decode(a, { isAttributeValue: true }),//default is a=>a
                tagValueProcessor: a => he.decode(a) //default is a=>a
            };
            // Intermediate obj
            var tObj = parser.getTraversalObj(response.data, options);
            var jsonObj = parser.convertToJson(tObj, options);
            if (jsonObj["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"].GetAllCategoriesResponse.GetAllCategoriesResult["diffgr:diffgram"].DocumentElement != null) {
                var jsonDropDownDetails = jsonObj["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"].GetAllCategoriesResponse.GetAllCategoriesResult["diffgr:diffgram"].DocumentElement.CATEGORY

                jsonDropDownDetails.map(item => {
                    const data = { value: item.CATEGORYNAME, label: item.CATEGORYNAME, index: item.CATEGORYID }
                    setDropDownOptions(dropDownOptions.push(data))
                })
                callback(dropDownOptions)
            }
        }).catch(function (error) {

            console.log("erorr in DropDown : " + error)
        })
    };
```

and this is my `handelChange` method:

```
const handleChange = selectedOption => {
        console.log(selectedOption)
    };
```

and this is my AsyncSelect:

```
         <AsyncSelect
            styles={customStyles}
            cacheOptions
            loadOptions={loadOptions}
            defaultOptions
            onInputChange={handleChange}
            isRtl={true}
            isSearchable={false}
            classNamePrefix='myDropDown'
        />
```

how to callback which value is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `onInputChange` to `onChange` without changing your handler, `selectedOption` now should work

```
onChange={handleChange}
```